# tensor flow install problems

Tags: tensorflow, pip

the command

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

doesn`t work. 
I know that gaps in the directories/path names can cause problems. Therefore I tried to specify the path of the installation as an installation-condition

```
 pip3 install tensorflow -t=C:\Users\my HP-Probook\.spyder-py3
```

But that doesn't work either

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve your problem, but -t parameter probably expects its input in `"` to avoid confusion with spaces

Comment: Elaborate "*doesn't work*". Error messages?

Comment: @QmlnR2F5 Good point. But that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @phd The following error message appears "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" as if he didn't know the command at all

Comment: @phd With the command            "pip install tensorflow -t=C:\Users\my HP-Probook\.spyder-py3"       The following error message appears: "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages. The command "C:\Users\my " is either misspelled or could not be found."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: Thanks, at least that showed me where mwin error is. Now I have entered the command     "pip install tensorflow"       in Windows Power Shell and I get the following error message:  "pip: The name" pip "was not used as the name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file or an executable
Program detected. Check the spelling of the name, or whether the path is correct (if included), and
repeat the process.
In line: 1 character: 1
+ pip install tensorflow
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (pip: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException "